# Loaded OSM Data into PostGIS Database. Cannot view in ArcMap "The coordinate system identifier is invalid"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcmap, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I loaded OSM File for Pennsylvania into a PostGIS Database in PostgreSQL using osm2pgsql. Everything seemed to go without a hitch until I finally connected to the Database in arcCatalog and tried to view the layers. My plan was to use these for a basemap. When I tried to view the layers I was getting the following error and I'm not sure if there is a resolution to this, I have never seen it before.

[image]

Comment: Can you please try the `Find_SRID` function and edit in the result? http://postgis.net/docs/Find_SRID.html

Comment: are you using query layer? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_query_layer/00s500000027000000/ you can't edit without arcsde. for basemap raster would be a better solution

Comment: Yes I'm using a query layer. I do not intend to edit these layers

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup I tried the Find_SRID and it returned "couldn't find the corresponding SRID = is the geometry registered in the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table? Is there an uppercase/lowercase missmatch?" I did notice that the geometry_columns View is in lowercase. Could that be causing an issue?

Comment: @Mapperz. I understand that raster is better for a basemap, I have complaints that the basemaps are taking too long to load for users during peak network times, so I am trying an in-house solution. The next stage of this is to rasterize this in the future.

Comment: Can you always include errors as text rather than pictures, please?  That way they are easier to read on all devices and can be available to searches.